# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\Users

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-start

[image: Error Log Image in the link..]

When npm start "ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js" , this throws up every time.

For Reference I use Angular Versions:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/localize": "^9.0.4",
        "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "~9.0.3"
}
```

I tried to npm install querystring , but that didnt work, it throws up another error

Comment: Remove your package-lock file and do a npm install --force

Comment: Yep I have tried , also tried using npm cache clean --force @user3837019